# Is it possible to read unread inbox mails in java using mailgun?

Tags: java, email, mailgun

Is it possible to read unread inbox mails in java using mailgun? Inbox can be any - gmail or yahoo or hotmail or xyz. And after reading, mails must be marked as read.
If possible, please share java code snippet for the same.
I don't want to use Maven either.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Also, if you don't want to use Maven.. what do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

No.

[Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) is a PaaS for, mainly, sending emails. It has some functionality regarding receiving messages (useful for bounces and so) but it cannot access any kind of external mail storage or service via IMAP, POP or anything like that.

If you want to access some email inbox you don't need an external service. You can do it with java libraries. The standard library is [Javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javamail).

With that you can, for example, access via IMAP4 a email account.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have found the answer useful please accept and upvote it. Thanks!